# Pandas unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas

`df_ppc.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 892 entries, 0 to 891
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Player     892 non-null object
Mean       892 non-null object
Team       892 non-null object
Position   892 non-null object
```

If I groupi like so:

```
df = df_ppc.groupby(['Player'])['Mean'].max().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

It works.

If I group it like so:

```
df = df_ppc.groupby(['Player', 'Team'])['Mean'].max().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

It throws:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1798, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1718, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

---

Why? how do I fix this?

EDIT:

SampleTable:

```
        Player        Mean      Team  \
715  Richard Franco   0.2354   Avaí   
12       Alan Costa   0.6543   CSA   
14      Alan Santos   0.0345   Botafogo   

           Posicao 
715  Meio-Campista       
12        Zagueiro         
14   Meio-Campista
```

df_pcc was built like so:

```
position = df_players.groupby('Player')['position'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
team = df_players.groupby('Team')['time_nome'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
mean = df_players.groupby('atleta_nome').mean()['points']

df_ppc = pd.DataFrame([team, position, mean]).T

df_ppc.columns = ['Team','Position','Mean']   

df_ppc = df_ppc.reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you show the sample table

Comment: @YOBEN_S like that?

Comment: You have type of np.array in Team ?

Comment: Does `Team` column contain numpy arrays?

Comment: @Ankur please refer to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the `df_ppc`, get the mode only pick the first one , since the function will return a series not single value

```
position = df_players.groupby('Player')['position'].agg(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
team = df_players.groupby('Team')['time_nome'].agg(lambda x : x.mode().iloc[0])
```

For example

```
pd.Series([1,1,2,2]).mode()
Out[24]: 
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```